# Find value in an @Hash field type with mongodb-odm

Tags: mongodb, symfony-2.1, doctrine-odm

I really new to mongoDb and I have a problem.

i have this field in a collection:

```
data: [ "data1", "data2" ]
```

Why this query via console works :

db.collection.find({'data': /data1/})

but this no?

```
 $hasData = $this->documentManager->createQueryBuilder('Document\\Collection')
        ->field('data')->equals( new \MongoRegex('/data1/'))
        ->count()
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

Where I'm wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved by adding another discriminatory:

```
$hasData = $this->documentManager->createQueryBuilder('Document\\Collection')
        ->field('data')->equals( new \MongoRegex('/data1/'))
        ->field('_id')->equals(new \MongoId($user->getId()))
        ->count()
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an elemMatch() expression to the field.

```
->field('my_field')->elemMatch($qb->expr()->field('data')->equals('data1'))
```